# Why do i get the message ' Line search fails in two-class probability estimates' when using libsvm for binary classification'?

Tags: libsvm

I am suddenly facing the problem wherein i get the message ' Line search fails in two-class probability estimates' when using libsvm for binary classification' when classifying the test images . The training database is of size 2000 and test database is of size 2000. The feature vector size is 200. However, for another feature of size 256, the problem does not arise. Even for other large size features the problem didnot occur.Suddenly the problem has occured. I am using LIBSVM and it is binary classification. What can be the possible reason? Please help asap.Thanks in advance.
I have tried the solution suggested in earlier similar question,but of no use.